# Linux Updates failing

Tags: software-installation

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu, I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit.

I've been having a problem with my apps updating, i keep getting the error when i try to update from the appstore which it is prompting, that doesn't work so i try the reapir option which comes up with 'Package operation failed' bellow is the details scrip from the error message:

```
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ... 
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-power-manager' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-color-manager' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-control-center-shared-data' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-session-bin' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-shell-common' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-packagekit-session' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-shell' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-applets' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-tetravex' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-klotski' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-screensaver' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-desktop3-data' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-panel-data' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-user-share' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-online-accounts' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-mahjongg' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-applets-data' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-icon-theme-extras' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-documents' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-terminal-data' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-tweak-tool' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-disk-utility' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-settings-daemon-schemas' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-shell-extensions' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-themes-standard-data' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-bluetooth' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-orca' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-online-miners' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-icon-theme-full' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-session' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-sushi' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-nibbles' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-icon-theme' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-packagekit' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-calculator' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-control-center' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-media' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-backgrounds' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-session-common' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-menus' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-session-canberra' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-games' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-font-viewer' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-sudoku' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-dictionary' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-mines' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-keyring' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-nettool' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-control-center-data' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-session-flashback' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-accessibility-themes' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-contacts' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-panel' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-icon-theme-symbolic' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-packagekit-data' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-system-log' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-core' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-chess' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-themes-standard:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-settings-daemon' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-system-monitor' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-user-guide' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-terminal' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-video-effects' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-robots' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnome-screenshot' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 199694 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libreoffice-common_1%3a4.2.4-0ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-common (1:4.2.4-0ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a4.2.4-0ubuntu2_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/soffice', which is also in package openoffice-debian-menus 4.1-9764
rmdir: failed to remove /var/lib/libreoffice/share/prereg/: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove /var/lib/libreoffice/share/: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove /var/lib/libreoffice/program/: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove /var/lib/libreoffice: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove /var/lib/libreoffice: No such file or directory
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-icon-theme (3.10.0-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.2-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a4.2.4-0ubuntu2_all.deb
Error in function: 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-l10n-en-gb:
 libreoffice-l10n-en-gb depends on libreoffice-common; however:
  Package libreoffice-common is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-l10n-en-gb (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-l10n-en-za:
 libreoffice-l10n-en-za depends on libreoffice-common; however:
  Package libreoffice-common is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-l10n-en-za (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

any help with this would be brilliant,
I uninstalled libreoffice from the PC.

Comment: The easiest way to format large blocks of inserted code is to highlight the block, and press ctrl-k

Comment: What command are you using to try to perform an update?

Comment: What external repos/PPAs are you using?

Comment: @CharlesGreen, I originally wasn't using a command, I was using the software centre 'repair'. I did also try the force install 'sudo apt-get -f install' but that gave similar results. I can post up the code error code if that would help.

Comment: @saiarcot895, my 'other software' PPA's are as follows,
chrome,
Openoffice
Steam
and another called 'office' 
(I was just picking the key word out the PPA, i can post the full ones if that will help)
I have tried unticking the PPA's and trying again with not luck.

Comment: Remove `openoffice-debian-menus`, and run `sudo apt-get install -f`. Also, I believe LibreOffice has more features and is more actively developed than OpenOffice. Also, your Ubuntu installation might be messed up, because `dpkg` is saying that it doesn't have the list of files installed by many Gnome packages, and if you are using Gnome, this is a bit of a problem for you.

Comment: @saiarcot895, hi cheers for the help. I tried what you suggested with no luck, the error code was the same as the original post.

Comment: @LiamBrown: Have you tried `dpkg --purge openoffice-debian-menus` (and bypass `apt-get`)?

Comment: @saiarcot895, BRILLIANT! it installed fine after that. thank you very much for your help :)